# Does Apple make a modem?

Tags: time-capsule, internet, modem

I just bought a Time Capsule, and the lack of modem is irritating, as this means I have to buy a seperate one which is another box, won't be as easy to set up and I have to choose one.

Does Apple make a modem themselves, that can be used with a Time Capsule simply and easily? If they don't is there a suggested one for a Time Capsule?

EDIT: I live in the UK, my ISP is TalkTalk and it is ADSL.

Comment: @Nathan, I didn't use strong wording???

Comment: He just removed subjective statements.

Comment: Generally, any time a question or answer contains something subjective that someone could take offense with, we edit it out (provided the meaning isn't altered). You aren't in any trouble or anything, just something to keep in mind for future posts. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: Don't get upset when you get collaboratively edited, it's usually just for clarity and to remove stuff that simply isn't required to answer the question.

Comment: Exactly what method do you use to connect to the Internet, through which service provider company, and where do you live? The answers depend on that. See my answer. below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple don't make a modem, but depending on your internet/cable/fiber provider, you may be able to encourage them to give you one for free.

I have Virgin Media in the UK and new customers receive a new Super Hub free (which can easily be configured to be a slave modem, you just turn the wireless off). The same is true of most of the free 'hubs' provided by networks these days.

Comment: I've found these free ones to be quite unreliable, all of the free ones I've had from my ISPs have broken, and the one I've bought that I'm using now is on it's last legs.

Comment: Which provider do you have? Their normally pretty tough, and when ours failed, Virgin gave us a new one for free. They were actually happy to provide us with a cable one. With that said, it is an additional box however you look at it - but Apple do not make a standalone modem.

Comment: TalkTalk, they gave a cheap (as in feel/look) SpeedTouch thing, it overheated within a few months.

Comment: Give them a ring- especially if you are within maybe a year of them providing it and they should replace for free. If you're not within your contract year, call and threaten to leave - they'll jump through hoops and do more or less anything you ask them too.

Comment: I'll try calling them, but being TalkTalk my hopes are low :)

Comment: Aye, I've never heard happy things about them. Although, the service can't really be as bad as Virgin ;)

Answer (score 1):

They do not make a modem, at least not an external one.  I'm sure older Macs have them but that's not appropriate for your requirements, and they were not ADSL modems anyway.

I have found that there are few modems available (although there is one DLINK one and a [TP-LINK](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/?categoryid=221&model=TD-8616) one that looks useful, but I have found that the cheapest way to sort one out is to get almost any old Wireless Router with a modem built in, and configure it in Bridge mode that basically turns off all routing/firewall/NAT/DHCP/Wireless etc functions, and just let's the Apple router (Time Capsule, Airport Extreme Router, etc) pass the old router a username and password and ask it to make the connection and pass the traffic through the link.

I currently use a DLINK DSL2740B Wireless Modem Router in this way, just using the modem functionality.

Using Bridge mode is a far better way than running an old router in normal mode and just turning the wireless off, as it allows proper configuration of back to my Mac etc and allows you to use the standard OS X tools for managing your network rather than having to remember some weirdo IP address and do it all via a dodgy web interface.

Answer (score 1):

There are many kinds of modems, because there are many different technologies used to provide an Internet connection. Which one are you using?

By "modem" you could mean dial-up telephone (POTS), or any of a variety of ADSL, cable TV, fiber-optic-to-the-premises like AT&T UVerse, T-1, or many other types of modems. These vary around the world depending on the technology that the various Internet service providers use.

So which "suggested one" model of modem for a Time Capsule would depend entirely on which Internet service provider company you are using, and what kind of method of connecting you to the Internet you are paying for (dial-up telephone, DSL, cable TV, fiber optic, satellite dish, etc.), and ultimately what country in the world you live in. This is not a question with a simple answer.

Apple doesn't make modems, because there's no way that Apple could make all the many different devices that would be required to work with all the different Internet service providers all over the world. There are some Internet service providers that won't even let a customer choose or purchase their own modem for certain kinds of services; they require that you rent the equipment directly from them.

All you need to do is to use whatever method of connection you have to your Internet service provider (the "modem"), and read its manual to find out how to put it in "bridge mode" or "DMZ mode" so that you can connect your Apple Time Capsule or Apple AirPort directly to the modem, and have all your computing devices connect to the Apple Time Capsule's router.